# IE, Edge replaces storage text with 'null'

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I have this little contact form on my site, and it's suppose to input some text into an empty p tag telling the client that's it's been submitted. It works fine, it does what it should, but in IE/Edge it ignores everything and inputs the word null into the p tags.

You'll have to forgive me, I'm still new to javascript, but I couldn't find anything anywhere to address this bug. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return setReturn()">
  <input type="hidden" value="someone@email.com" name="emailTo">
  <fieldset>
  <p id="thanks"></p>
  <legend>Send me a message</legend>
  <div class="contact-info">
   <input placeholder="Name*" type="text" name="name" required>
   <input placeholder="Email*" type="Email" name="email" required>
  </div>
   <textarea placeholder="Message*" name="message" required></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitContact" class="button">
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script>
  function setReturn(){
   localStorage.setItem("thanks", "Your request was sent successfully!");
  }

  document.getElementById("thanks").innerHTML =    localStorage.getItem("thanks");
  localStorage.clear();
</script>
```

Comment: When `document.getElementById("thanks").innerHTML =    localStorage.getItem("thanks");` fires, that localStorage item is null. It never fires again *after* the localStorage item is set to anything.

Comment: this seems like an odd use for `localStorage`....

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that when the innerHTML of the "thanks" element is set, the string in localStorage is unset.

Then when the form is submitted, the localStorage item is set, but the "thanks" element's innerHTML isn't set (it was set to undefined before).

In order to make sure the "thanks" element is updated when the form is submitted, you need to include the lines that set it in the function that fires when the form is submitted.

```
function setReturn(){
  localStorage.setItem("thanks", "Your request was sent successfully!");
  document.getElementById("thanks").innerHTML =    localStorage.getItem("thanks");
  localStorage.clear();
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On form submit you are calling setReturn function , but when this snippet `document.getElementById("thanks").innerHTML =    localStorage.getItem("thanks");` is parsed `localStorage` does not have this key. So you have to first set this local storage before use it's value as innerHTML like in the previous answer. 
Also it is odd that you are using localStorge and even you are clearing it, when this thing can be acheived by this snippet

HTML

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return setReturn()">
  <input type="hidden" value="someone@email.com" name="emailTo">
  <fieldset>
  <p id="thanks"></p>
  <legend>Send me a message</legend>
  <div class="contact-info">
   <input placeholder="Name*" type="text" name="name" required>
   <input placeholder="Email*" type="Email" name="email" required>
  </div>
   <textarea placeholder="Message*" name="message" required></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitContact" class="button">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS

```
function setReturn(){
event.preventDefault()
   document.getElementById("thanks").innerHTML = "Your request was sent successfully!";
  }
```

NOTE: I used `event.preventDefault` just for demo but in real application you dont need to use it as it will prevent default behaviour or the submit button.

Here is a [WORKING COPY](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/t1eokqa1/2/)

Also you can use an IIF to set up this localStorage.This function will be executed as soon as it parsed and will set up the key `thanks` to it.

```
(function(){
localStorage.setItem("thanks", "Your request was sent successfully!");
}())
```

Then onsubmit you can use your function without making any change

```
function setReturn(){
event.preventDefault();
document.getElementById("thanks").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("thanks");
  localStorage.clear();
}
```

[WORKING COPY WITH IIF](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/t1eokqa1/3/)

Hope this is helpful